# How to start learning about artificial intelligence?

Tags: research

I have been wanting to get started learning about artificial intelligence but I know almost nothing about coding or anything. So my question is, what would be the best way to get started in learning about artificial intelligence, as in should I learn some kind of coding language or is there some kind of other concept you need to know before getting started. So I'm just kind of looking for the best way to get started if you literally know nothing.

Comment: Welcome to AI.SE. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to be about the social or scientific/academic aspects of artificial intelligence. ([Relevant meta discussion.](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/q/74/75)) If you poke around a bit more on the Internet, I suspect you'll discover some interesting things that we *can* help with!

Answer (score 3):

Read:

'Artificial Intelligence - A modern approach' by Russell and Norvig.

'Fluid Concepts and Creative Analogies' by Douglas Hofstadter.

'Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition' by Bishop

'The Emotion Machine' by Marvin Minsky